# Can't find sqlite3 library under Xcode 4.3.2 & iPhone Simulator 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm working on a project that uses sqlite3.  When I build the project, I get an error on this statement `sqlite3 _wordsClues;` the error is `Unknown type name 'sqlite3'` so it seems the library can't be found.  I have `libsqlite3.0.dylib` linked in the build phase.  There is another option there I could use called `libsqlite3.dylib` but I haven't used it.

In my pch I have had at various points `<sqlite3.h>` `"sqlite3.h"` and `"/usr/include/sqlite3.h"`  None of these combinations have worked (found by looking around on SO).

Any suggestions?  I must be missing something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: try the libsqlite3.dylib. it's worked for me.

Comment: @JesseNaugher which `#import` statement did you use with that library?

Comment: "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

Comment: @JesseNaugher Alas, that combination doesn't work for me... :-(

Comment: is that a typo in your declaration? it should be a pointer. `sqlite3 *library` but not sure that would make that error message

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem.  I had actually experimented with that, as I read somewhere that `sqlite3` is a C struct and hence one should not use a pointer.  Consistent with that, I also have `@property (assign, nonatomic) sqlite3 wordsClues;` but I'm not certain this is the right approach either.

Answer (score 3):

This page: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/Tutorial-on-Creating-an-IOS-5-SQLite-Database-Application-IOS-5-SQLite has a very good example with the exact steps.

Basically, you need to link against `usr/lib/sqlite_3.0.lib` and `#import <sqlite3.h>`

Comment: Thanks, I can use that link.  But looking specifically at their instructions, the file they suggest doesn't exist on my machine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Inafziger The method at the link leads to the same files as going to the build phase and adding a library.  The libsqlite3.0.dylib is actually an alias to libsqlite3.dylib.  There is no sqlite_3.0.lib and at one point in the tutorial it calls it sqlite3.0.dylib